# PHPExcel - Read cell value on linux centos producing extra character

Tags: php, phpexcel

i have a problem using PHPExcel object reader on centos. The program itself is created and tested on windows, and it has no problem. But when i am throwing it to centos, all of textvalue contain extra character like <?>. I have trying to change default_charset of php.ini to UTF-8 but it seems no use. Is there anything that i need to see ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing that i am never think about is updating PHPExcel version to latest current version (1.7.6) because it was 1.7.2. Then after i have update it, my code works perfectly. But i don't really know whats going on under the hood. Shame on me.